# Eclipse cdt debugging an executable within a shell script

Tags: debugging, eclipse-cdt

I recently started using Eclipse CDT on Linux and like it a lot!!!

I am able to find an answer to almost everything.

I am unable to invoke debugger on a simple executable and I need to do it after running a quite big shell script which sets many environment variables.

My question is simply how to do it, so that eventually, I'll be able to invoke the debugger (GDB) where all environment variables are set by some pre-running shell script.

Alternatively, how do setup a script which - as first stage - sets up the environment, and eventually invokes the Eclipse CDT debugger.

Your assistance is much appreciated.

Regards,
-Zvika